# How To Add MVC3 SqlMembershipProvider With SQLCE4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sqlmembershipprovider, sql-server-ce-4

I'm not quite sure if this has been asked or discussed elsewhere but I'm trying to implement the SqlMembershipProvider but I also want to use SQLCE4.  I feel that having to have not only two databases but having two separate "server" systems drive those databases is a bad design.  So, my question is, anyone know how to setup a connection entry in the web.config for the SQLCE db that is created when using the EF4/MvcScaffolder?  I have a custom MembershipProvider that implements the System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider and would like to modify it to use the SQLCE db.  If not, maybe I could modify it to use DbContext?

Thanks Ahead...
Keith

**UPDATE:**

So, I have created a connection string:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|MVC3BlogEngine.Models.MVC3BlogEngineContext.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

But when I attempt to create a user using the string I get the following error:

> *"An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
>   Parameter name: connectionString"*

Now, looking at my connection string, maybe the path is wrong.  So, I will update it and post the result...

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed the connection string to have the absolute full path to the sdf file but still no luck.  I'm assuming the provider is specific to SqlProvider when I need to somehow change it to SqlCe.4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran a membership provider implementation for a small project using sqlce and [this sqlce membership provider](http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com/).  It was a very small project but I had no problems with it.

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer.  I've used that provider before and it's not too bad.  It does what I need it to do and it's lightweight.